# Flutter ListView Load Data from Nested JSON

Tags: json, flutter

I've been trying some code from [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51)

I'm trying to load data from local JSON, this JSON is nested model, here's the JSON.

***list.json*** :

```
{
    "response": "200",
    "categorylist": [
        {
            "categoryId": 1,
            "categoryTitle": "Working",
            "categoryPost": [
                {
                    "postId": 1,
                    "postTitle": "Some Working Title",
                    "reference": "Some Working Reference",
                    "postContent": [
                        {
                            "contentId": 1,
                            "author": "Some Author Name 1",
                            "content": "Some long content long content long content 1",
                            "note": "Some notes 1",
                            "explanation": "Some Explanation 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "contentId": 2,
                            "author": "Some Author Name 2",
                            "content": "Some long content long content long content 2",
                            "note": "Some notes 2",
                            "explanation": "Some Explanation 2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "postId": 2,
                    "postTitle": "Some Title 2",
                    "reference": "Some reference 2",
                    "postContent": [
                        {
                            "contentId": 1,
                            "author": "Some Author Name 1",
                            "content": "Some long content long content long content 1",
                            "note": "Some notes 1",
                            "explanation": "Some Explanation 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "contentId": 2,
                            "author": "Some Author Name 2",
                            "content": "Some long content long content long content 2",
                            "note": "Some notes 2",
                            "explanation": "Some Explanation 2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "categoryId": 2,
            "categoryTitle": "Order",
            "categoryPost": [
                {
                    "postId": 1,
                    "postTitle": "Some Order Title",
                    "reference": "Some Order Reference",
                    "postContent": [
                        {
                            "contentId": 1,
                            "author": "Some Author Name 1",
                            "content": "Some long content long content long content 1",
                            "note": "Some notes 1",
                            "explanation": "Some Explanation 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "contentId": 2,
                            "author": "Some Author Name 2",
                            "content": "Some long content long content long content 2",
                            "note": "Some notes 2",
                            "explanation": "Some Explanation 2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "postId": 2,
                    "postTitle": "Some Title 2",
                    "reference": "Some reference 2",
                    "postContent": [
                        {
                            "contentId": 1,
                            "author": "Some Author Name 1",
                            "content": "Some long content long content long content 1",
                            "note": "Some notes 1",
                            "explanation": "Some Explanation 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "contentId": 2,
                            "author": "Some Author Name 2",
                            "content": "Some long content long content long content 2",
                            "note": "Some notes 2",
                            "explanation": "Some Explanation 2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and here's my ***list_model.dart*** :

```
class Category {
  String response;
  List<Categorylist> categorylist;

  Category({this.response, this.categorylist});

  Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    response = json['response'];
    if (json['categorylist'] != null) {
      categorylist = new List<Categorylist>();
      json['categorylist'].forEach((v) {
        categorylist.add(new Categorylist.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['response'] = this.response;
    if (this.categorylist != null) {
      data['categorylist'] = this.categorylist.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Categorylist {
  int categoryId;
  String categoryTitle;
  List<CategoryPost> categoryPost;

  Categorylist({this.categoryId, this.categoryTitle, this.categoryPost});

  Categorylist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    categoryId = json['categoryId'];
    categoryTitle = json['categoryTitle'];
    if (json['categoryPost'] != null) {
      categoryPost = new List<CategoryPost>();
      json['categoryPost'].forEach((v) {
        categoryPost.add(new CategoryPost.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['categoryId'] = this.categoryId;
    data['categoryTitle'] = this.categoryTitle;
    if (this.categoryPost != null) {
      data['categoryPost'] = this.categoryPost.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class CategoryPost {
  int postId;
  String postTitle;
  String reference;
  List<PostContent> postContent;

  CategoryPost({this.postId, this.postTitle, this.reference, this.postContent});

  CategoryPost.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    postId = json['postId'];
    postTitle = json['postTitle'];
    reference = json['reference'];
    if (json['postContent'] != null) {
      postContent = new List<PostContent>();
      json['postContent'].forEach((v) {
        postContent.add(new PostContent.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['postId'] = this.postId;
    data['postTitle'] = this.postTitle;
    data['reference'] = this.reference;
    if (this.postContent != null) {
      data['postContent'] = this.postContent.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class PostContent {
  int contentId;
  String author;
  String content;
  String note;
  String explanation;

  PostContent(
      {this.contentId, this.author, this.content, this.note, this.explanation});

  PostContent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    contentId = json['contentId'];
    author = json['author'];
    content = json['content'];
    note = json['note'];
    explanation = json['explanation'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['contentId'] = this.contentId;
    data['author'] = this.author;
    data['content'] = this.content;
    data['note'] = this.note;
    data['explanation'] = this.explanation;
    return data;
  }
}
```

here's my ***view_list.dart*** :

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'model.dart';

  Future<String>  _loadCategoryfromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/list.json');
  }

  Future loadCategory() async {
    await wait(1);
    String jsonString = await _loadCategoryfromAssets();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    Category category = Category.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print(category.categorylist[0].categoryTitle);
    print(category.categorylist[0].categoryPost[0].postTitle);    
  }

  Future wait(int seconds) {
    return new Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: seconds), () => {});
  }

class Doa extends StatefulWidget {
  Doa({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _DoaState createState() => _DoaState();
}

class _DoaState extends State<Doa> {

  Widget futureWidget() {
    return new FutureBuilder(
      future: loadCategory(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return new Container(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          snapshot.data.category.categorylist[index].categoryTitle,
                        ),
                      )

                      ],
                    );
                  }
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        } 
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        top: false,
        bottom: false,
        child: Scaffold(
        body: futureWidget(),
        ));
  }
}
```

I'm stuck load the data from JSON inside categorylist into listview.builder.

in the view code above, I'm only want to list all "categoryTitle" from json, with ontap action to detail page. how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve this problem, write into listviewBuilder with this code inside a widget :

```
  Widget futureWidget() {
    return new FutureBuilder(
      future: loadCategory(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return new Container(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          snapshot.data.category.categorylist[index].categoryTitle,
                        ),
                      )

                      ],
                    );
                  }
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        } 
      },
    );
  }
```

and then I add this code below to load nested json :

```
  Future<String>  _loadCategoryfromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/list.json');
  }

  Future loadCategory() async {
    await wait(1);
    String jsonString = await _loadCategoryfromAssets();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    Category category = Category.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print(category.categorylist[0].categoryTitle);
    print(category.categorylist[0].categoryPost[0].postTitle);    
  }

  Future wait(int seconds) {
    return new Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: seconds), () => {});
  }
```